# Good practices to manage user session data with vue and laravel API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, session, vuejs2

I am building a `single-page application` with `Vue` and `laravel` API as backend.
I've tried some `packages` like [Vue Session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-session) and it worked well, however in almost every `API` call I always need to send 2 or 3 parameters that will always be the same (stored in `vue-session`), like `user_id` and `company_id`. I used to manage this with common `PHP sessions` (`Zend_Session` with `Zend Framework`) in my other applications, this way I always have that information stored in my `backend`  `session` and don't need to send it every time by the `frontend`

Here's an example of how I used to do it with `PHP session`

```
$model->insert(array(
    'user_id' => $this->session->user_id, //stored in session
    'company_id' => $this->session->company_id, //stored in session
    'field1' => $this->getParam('field1'), //frontend param (ajax)
    'field2' => $this->getParam('field2') //frontend param (ajax)
));
```

And here's how I'm doing it with `Vue` and `Laravel`

```
const data = {
    user_id: this.$session.get('user_id'), //this is what i'm trying to get rid of
    company_id: this.$session.get('company_id'), //this is what i'm trying to get rid of²
    field1: this.field1,
    field2: this.field2
}

axios
   .post('/api/some/endpoint', this.data)
   .then(resp => {
      //...//
})
```

Basically, in this example I want to not need to always send `user_id` and `company_id` as a `post` `param`.

Is there any way to get better code "reuse" in cases like this?

Comment: It might be worth looking at Laravel Passport (specifically the **Consuming Your API With JavaScript**) https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: I'm actually using laravel passport, and the token is send by default on axios headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, You can save your session data in the cookie. The browser will automatically send your cookie to the server. Don't forget to delete the cookie when the user logout.

2, If you still want to use Vue session or other storages, you can easily create a method that wraps your post method and add user's information to the payload

```
function postRequest(url, payload) {
    payload.user_id = this.$session.get('user_id')
    payload.company_id = this.$session.get('company_id')
    return axios.post(url, payload)
}
```

Use this method whenever you want to make a post.

Comment: If you are using this can somebody not just edit their cookies and change user data for any account?

Comment: @DrRoach I just used the OP code. Everything in the client can be manually changed you know that. So for your question, we need to implement an OAuth method like an access token or something.

Comment: As the question asks for good practises I think that using a token like JWT - https://jwt.io/ would be a much better suggestion.